# Making Sure JSON Objects Exist

Tags: javascript, json

If i have javascript code that depends on data from a response containing data… is there a preferred way to check that the JSON object returned has an expected structure?

Right now i have this and it seems terrible:

```
if (jsonResults !== null && jsonResults.SomeItem !==  && jsonResults.SomeItem.aProperty !== null) {
  // Some Code
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/).

Comment: It does seem terrible. Might I ask why you don't know what the schema is? Are you not the one sending it?

Comment: use (x != null) instead of (x !== null) so you can hit null and undefined at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Simply your statement to the following:

```
if (jsonResults && jsonResults.SomeItem && jsonResults.SomeItem.aProperty) {
  // Some Code
}
```

In JavaScript evaluations are [Truthy/Falsey](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/). `null` is considered falsey and will be caught by the above evaluation.

Comment: Consider comparing `jsonResults.SomeItem.aProperty != null` in case it is a valid falsey value. (e.g. 0, "", or false)

Comment: Could do something along the lines of 
`typeof jsonResults === "object"`
for detecting if the entire object is a json struct